# Change the color of the drop-down menu-item

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to change the color of the drop-down menu item when the mouse hover is on, from blue to be black when the mouse hover is on the item, please take a look at the picture below: 
https://ibb.co/5ss9YfC

If you need to inspect details, please login with a demo account and inspect it:
http://116.202.31.216/gps/
email: demo
password: demo

I think this is the code of the element that I want to change the hover color, so what can I insert here to change the color:

```
.x-menu-item {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    background-color: black!important;
}
```

Comment: To apply CSS on hover you must use `:hover` selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the following CSS:

```
.x-menu-item-default.x-menu-item-focus, .x-menu-item-default.x-menu-item-active {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #7fb5e4;
}
```

to

```
.x-menu-item-default.x-menu-item-focus, .x-menu-item-default.x-menu-item-active {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Mohammad. You are great.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:hover` class in css.

```
.x-menu-item:hover {
    color: blue;
}
```

learn more about :hover [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp)

Answer (score 0):

if this didn't answer your query would you be able to elaborate a bit more on the result you are looking for.

as per your question the following should do the trick

```
.x-menu-item:hover {
cursor:pointer;
color: #preferedcolorHexcode;
background:#preferedcolorHexcode;
}
```

hope this helps answer your query.

Answer (score 0):

Use `:hover` and `background-color`, like so:

```css
.x-menu-item {
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope below mentioned code will help you.

```
.x-menu-item:hover {
   background-color:#000000;
} 
or
.x-menu-item:hover,
.x-menu-item:focus,
.x-menu-item:focus:hover,
.x-menu-item:active:hover {
   background-color:#000000;
}
```